# While Rotating Parent Distance Measurement Gives Unexpected Results in Unity Script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

We are measuring distance with rays for several reasons like to detect the edge etc.
like you could see in the image below.

It works well unless we rotate parent in application 2.

In application 1 it measures current distance correctly at least they are not 0 while we rotate the parent.

But in application 2 we are getting 0 distance even if the child is not moving.

When rotation axis perpendicular to screen.

This is the code I use to measure distance from Child to Parent surface;

```
private void GetBackDist()
{

    backDist = 0f;
    Vector3 raycastDirection = -back1.transform.up;
    Ray ray = new(back1.transform.position, raycastDirection);
    
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit, 0.7f))
    {
        if (hit.collider.CompareTag("world"))
        {
            backDist = hit.distance;
           
        }
    }

}
```

[image: ray application]

Comment: It would be easyer to help if you post your code. This problem could be related to the ray hitting the child itself or some other setting

Comment: I added code to measure distance from child to parent. I think there must be nothing unusual because child rotate as if it is part of parent naturally.

Comment: Your ray is starting in the middle of the back1 object positin, is it possible that it is hitting the child? Have you tryed debugging and checking which object is beeing hitted by the ray?

Comment: @RenanRuan because I changed my approach triggers events for the edge, I am a bit impatient, not following this at the moment I am sure I was doing something idiotic as usual.